# Adding show one a time functionality and slide animation to pre-existing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I've got a show/hide script I use on my website that works great. However there's 1 issue and one request.

1. Need to allow only 1 div at a time to show
2. When the div appears, to
   have it 'slide' in from underneath the header.

Here's the script:

```
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
         var e = document.getElementById(id);
         if(e.style.display == 'block')
                e.style.display = 'none';
         else
                e.style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Here is how the buttons work in relation to the div's in the HTML:

```
<a onclick="toggle_visibility('testing');">Testing</a>

<div style="display:none;" id="testing">
testing for page 2
</div>
```

Here is the layout of the screen in regards for the slide animation:

[image]

If anyone could help with adding these functions to the script or they have a different script that does the same thing but better please let me know. 
Thanks

Comment: have you tried something ? you will need to include some html too

Comment: @DaniP I've been messing with this script and others for the past couple hours now and just can't get it to work. I'm not very good at JavaScript yet and am still learning. **PS:** I added the HTML code for the buttons and their div's

Comment: You tag the question with jquery is that an option ? I don't know the solution with vanilla JS but with jquery

Comment: don't edit "solved" into your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with jQuery, then take a look at `slideToggle()`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      var activeDiv = 'welcome';
      function toggle_visibility(id) {            
        if ( activeDiv === id ) return;
        $('#' + activeDiv).css('display','none');
        activeDiv = id;
        $('#' + id).slideToggle();
        $('#' + id).css('display','block');
      };
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#welcome').slideToggle();
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="toggle_visibility('testing');">Show the First DIV</a><br>
    <a onclick="toggle_visibility('testing2');">Show the Second DIV</a>

    <div style="display: none;" id="testing">
      The First DIV
    </div>

    <div style="display: none;" id="welcome">
      Welcome!
    </div>

    <div style="display: none;" id="testing2">
      The Second DIV
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked thank you so much! **Extra** Do you know of a way to allow it so that a specific div with the id of 'welcome' opens by default? I tried doing this but it creates an issue where that one always displays and the other ones appear underneath it

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your help. I've been screwing with this for hours and now I've got it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Toggle slideUp() and slideDown()</button>

</body>
</html>
```